# How can I collect the pod logs using fluentd and send the logs to elasticsearch?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes, elastic-stack, fluentd

I am trying to push the stdout logs which we see using below command to the elastic search using fluentd. I am not sure what can I do?

`Kubectl logs -f <podname>`

This shows all the SYSOUT logs getting printed via Java application.
I want these logs to be available in elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check [this](https://docs.fluentd.org/v/0.12/articles/kubernetes-fluentd)?

From above link

1. Get fluentd deamonset
2. Tweak the deamonset manifest file like below(as mentioned in that link)

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: kube-system
  ...
spec:
    ...
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: fluentd
        image: quay.io/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset
        env:
          - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
            value: "elasticsearch-logging"
          - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
            value: "9200"
        ...
```